# Simple random walk on a disconnected graph

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let's say that there is a disconnected graph with two disjoint components. How I do show that the graph has 2 distinct stationary distributions? I'm trying to prove that there is infinitely many stationary distributions by taking a linear combination of two distinct ones.

Comment: you need to fill in more details here / possibly an example.  I am currently guessing that there are finitely many states.  The conclusion doesn't necessarily follow if there are countably $\infty$ many states.  In the finite state case your problem reduces to proving that the multiplicity of the perron root counts the number of (disjoint) communicating classes.  A standard technique -- show that the right eigenvector for a single communicating class in a Markov chain cannot have a distinct maximum or minimum (i.e. it must be proportional to the ones vector for those states).

Comment: @user8675309 I don't have an example unfortunately, as I'm just trying to understands a general statement that my prof said in lectures. I did write down, however, that we should use the fact that the transition matrix should be in the form of a block diagonal. I'm having trouble seeing how the blocks necessarily lead to distinct stationary distributions, say, pi1 and pi2.

Comment: your block diagonal matrix is n x n.  There’s two approaches- compute the characteristic polynomial and see how that works for a block diagonal matrix (there’s a lot on this site about that).  Or ‘attack’ the right eigenvectors and look at $S_n= \frac{1}{n}\big(P+ P^2 + P^3 + ... + P^{n-1} + P^n\big)$. Convince yourself that the blocks are strictly positive and each block can only have a constant vector as right fixed point ie there can’t be a distinct max and min since each eigenvector component is an average of other components associated with that block and averages can’t be extreme points

Comment: Actually I was pushing you to prove more than is needed... Consider that your upper block is r x r and your bottom block is (n-r)x (n-r). Now consider vector $\mathbf v_1$ that has r ones followed by n- r zeros. Confirm that $P \mathbf v_1 = \mathbf v_1$, so that’s an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1. Now consider ‘the complement’ given by $\mathbf v_2:= \mathbf 1 - \mathbf v_1$ and $P \mathbf v_2 = \mathbf v_2$.  So two linearly independent eigenvectors with eigenvalue 1 and each nicely lines up with one and only one communicating class. This implies something nice for left eigenvectors...

Comment: @user8675309 Thank you so much for all your help! I have several follow-up questions: How did you know to set v2 equal to 1-v1? (as in, how do we know that the "complement" is also en eigenvector of P? Also, just to clarify, v1 corresponds to the first block of P, and v2 to the second block, right? Finally, what's the importance of left eigenvectors here? I thought stationary distributions are always right eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post is specialized to (time homogenous) finite state markov chains.

For markov chains in the probability literature and most places, the transition matrix $P$ is *row stochastic* so $P\mathbf 1 = \mathbf 1$ and the steady state distribution is a left eigenvector of the transition matrix.  So

$\mathbf \pi^T P = \mathbf \pi^T$
(though often the transpose symbol is omitted)

A basic underappreciated result is for markov chains is that the multiplicity of the perron root (i.e. $\lambda = 1$) counts the number of distinct recurrent classes in a markov chain. The Perron root is always semisimple, and it is simple (i.e. algebraic multiplicity of 1) *iff* the markov chain is irreducible -- i.e. one recurrent class.  If a markov chain is not irreducible, then it is reducible.

For this problem we are told that the chain has a disconnected graph --i.e. it is reducible.  Typically the simple random walk is done on a countably infinite state space, so some details are missing in this problem statement.  (Further if the space was countably infinite the claim of at least 2 steady state distribution need not be true.)  In any case we are told the chain is reducible and has finitely many states and hence up to graph isomorphism the transition matrix is block diagonal.

$P = \begin{bmatrix}P_1 & 0 \\ 0 & P_2 \end{bmatrix}$

every n state  markov chain obeys $P\mathbf 1_n =\mathbf 1_n$.  But the distinct communicating class contained in $P_1$  (where we say $P_1$ is r x r) must obey $P_1\mathbf 1_r = \mathbf 1_r$-- if it didn't then a quick check of blocked multiplication would show that $P\mathbf 1_n \neq \mathbf 1_n$ which would be a contradiction.  This implies $\mathbf v_1 :=  \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf 1_r  \\  \mathbf 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector for $P$ (again by blocked multiplication).

So 
$P\mathbf 1_n = \mathbf 1_n$ and  $P\mathbf v_1 = \mathbf v_1$ and using linearity this implies
$\mathbf v_2 = \mathbf 1_n-  \mathbf v_1$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1 because
$P\mathbf v_2 = P\big(\mathbf 1_n-  \mathbf v_1\big)= P\mathbf 1_n-  P\mathbf v_1= \mathbf 1_n-  \mathbf v_1 = \mathbf v_2$

similarly direct calculation tells us that
$P\mathbf v_2 = \mathbf v_2 \longrightarrow P_2 \mathbf 1_{n-r} = \mathbf 1_{n-r}$

so $\big(P_1 - I_r\big)$ has a nonzero vector in its nullspace as does  $\big(P_2 - I_{n-r}\big)$.

Since row rank = column rank, in combination with rank-nullity, we know each $\big(P_1 - I_r\big)^T$ and $\big(P_2 - I_{n-r}\big)^T$ each have a non-zero vector in their nullspace.  Perron Frobenius theory tells us that these vectors must be strictly positive and after rescaling to ensure they sum to one, they *must* be $\mathbf \pi_1 \text{ and }\mathbf \pi_2$ respectively.  Since e.g. $\mathbf \pi_1^T P_1 = \mathbf \pi_1^T$, plugging this back into the original blocked structure tells us e.g. that

$\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf \pi_1  \\  \mathbf 0 \end{bmatrix}^T P =\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf \pi_1  \\  \mathbf 0 \end{bmatrix}^T$  and

$\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf 0  \\  \mathbf \pi_2 \end{bmatrix}^T P =\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf 0  \\  \mathbf \pi_2 \end{bmatrix}^T$

*In a nutshell:* a reducible chain implies (at least) 2 disjoint right eigenvectors with eigenvalue 1 which implies 2 disjoint left eigenvectors with eigenvalue 1. The standard approach is to then recurse on each smaller chain $P_1$ and $P_2$ and continue to apply the above techniques until the chain we are left working with is irreducible.

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you so much.